# How to check if variable trusted as HTML is empty in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, binding, angular-template

I have this situation:

```
<div ng-bind-html="model"></div>
<div ng-if="!model">Echo me if model is empty</div>
```

And in controller:

```
model = $sce.trustAsHtml(model);
```

How can I render second `<div>` only if `model` is (was before trusting it) empty string? I tried `ng-if="!model"` and `ng-if="model == ''"` but neither of these does work.

Comment: You provided code should work since the $sce.trustAsHtml will return the value itself if it is empty string or null or undefined. More information needed i think. If you would like to not show the div when it is null or undefined, you should use `model === ''`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MMhunter said, it **should work** (if `model` is empty string). I didn't include some details because I thought these are not relevant.

Basically, `model` is fetched via RESTful service, and empty model were saved in database as `null`. Because of that, neither `!model` nor `model == ''` worked. Now, `ng-if` is:

```
<div ng-if="model == '' || model == null">Echo me if model is empty</div>
```

and it works.

**Conclusion:** `$sce.trustAsHtml(str)` preserves `null` value (as well as `undefined` and empty string). AngularJS source:

```
function trustAs(type, trustedValue) {
  var Constructor = (byType.hasOwnProperty(type) ? byType[type] : null);
  if (!Constructor) {
    throw $sceMinErr('icontext',
        'Attempted to trust a value in invalid context. Context: {0}; Value: {1}',
        type, trustedValue);
  }
  if (trustedValue === null || isUndefined(trustedValue) || trustedValue === '') {
    return trustedValue; // <<< THIS IS RESPONSIBLE >>>
  }
  // All the current contexts in SCE_CONTEXTS happen to be strings.  In order to avoid trusting
  // mutable objects, we ensure here that the value passed in is actually a string.
  if (typeof trustedValue !== 'string') {
    throw $sceMinErr('itype',
        'Attempted to trust a non-string value in a content requiring a string: Context: {0}',
        type);
  }
  return new Constructor(trustedValue);
}
```